# Occasional graphics timing issue when waking up from suspend

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, graphics, suspend

I am running Ubuntu 16.04, fully up-to-date, with a GTX650 graphics card, using the Nvidia driver `v375.66`

Occasionally, when waking from suspend, my monitor shows me this:

[image]

Simply turning the monitor off, waiting 5 seconds, and then back on fixes the issue.

Before you guys say it's the monitor's issue, please know that I dual boot with Windows 7 and have never had this issue in Windows.

I have also tried `v340.102` of the Nvidia driver. No dice, the above issue still occasionally occurs.

**So, the question:** Is this a bug in the Nvidia driver for Linux, or maybe a bug in the X server, or something as simple as a misconfiguration?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a newer version of the nvidia drivers. I have no way of knowing whether this helps or not, but I think it is worth a shot. If it doesn't help you can always revert to the previous driver.

You can install a newer version from `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`.

To enable the PPA and install a newer verion of nvidia drivers, run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-381
```